# Can we call System registered COM DLL in Quartz.Net

Tags: dll, com, quartz.net

Suppose we have COM DLL registered in system registry. Now the requirement is to call that com dll functions in quartz.net.

I am thinking to make an auxiliary class that will contain implemented Execute method and using job data map I will call appropriate function in registered COM DLL. This is the way i am thinking to proceed.

Is there any other way that is easy and provide more flexibility.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what the question is here. Are you trying to have a job that can call any method on any COM DLL? If not, then using COM Interop (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kew41ycz(v=vs.110).aspx) inside a job that you write should suffice.